# Does GCC generate wrong assembly code for the "beq" instruction of riscv?

Tags: assembly, gcc, riscv, gnu-assembler

I have a riscv assembly code in beq.s

```
beq x0, x0, 42
```

And I compile it with

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -Wl,-Ttext=0x0 -nostdlib -march=rv64i -mabi=lp64 -o beq beq.s
```

Then I generate the raw riscv binary by

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-objcopy -O binary beq beq.bin
```

I use `hexdump -C beq.bin` to generate its hex code:

```
63 14 00 00 6f 00 00 00
```

Then I use `riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump` to disasm it. I got

```
bnez    zero,0x8
j       0x4
```

I think the `bnez` is wrong. It should be something like `beqz`.

May I do something wrong?

System: WSL ubuntu 20.04
gcc verison: 9.3.0

Comment: The assembler reversed your conditional to skip over a jump because you used an absolute address `42`. It also added a relocation entry that the linker was supposed to fill in. Since that did not happen, I think you accidentally copied from the object file not the linked binary which on my system has the correct `0260006f j 2a`.

Comment: You have found a pseudo instruction!  The instruction you wrote cannot be encoded exactly as written.  However, the assembler, being friendly, understands what that should mean, and converted it into a multi-instruction sequence that it can encode.  I can't explain why it chose that particular sequence since both the `beq` and the `j`/`jal` instruction are pc-relative, so neither can encode an absolute address; however the range of `jal` is larger than the range of `beq` so maybe that's why.  Generally speaking,  if you care about the object code, we should avoid pseudo instructions.

Comment: If you want to unconditionally transfer control to location 42, use `j 42` or `jalr x0, 42` instead of that `beq x0, x0, 42`.

Comment: beq is not a pseudo instruction. It is the `true` instruction defined in Riscv Spec. I have try almost the same command on clang-12.0. The result is correct. `beqz zero, 42`

Comment: the disassembler may be simply using a pseudo instruction to show the encoding of a real instruction.  similar to nop in arm or push saves typing stm sp! and knowing what that means.

Comment: If the assembler is expanding it into a multiple instruction sequence,, then it is a pseudo instruction form for that assembler, even if other ways of writing `beq` are true instructions and/or other assemblers accept this as a true instruction.